# Combine different types of jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to combine these jQuery calls? No real reason other than to tidy up my code a little.

```
$("#myForm input").blur(function() {
    saveForm();
});
$("#myForm :radio, #myForm :checkbox").click(function() {
    saveForm();
});
```

Comment: And how do you think these could be chained? The selected elements are different...

Comment: I'm not sure, hence the question. I just want to see if there's a single way of calling `saveForm()` rather than with these two seperate functions.

Comment: Use `change` event on `input` elements.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, as you suggested, `change` event is the way to go.  `$("#myForm input, #myForm :radio, #myForm :checkbox").change(function() { saveForm(); });`

Comment: `.change(saveForm)` is a lot tidier. There's no need for the anonymous function if all it does is call `saveForm()` with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn! In that case, I have a lot of tidying up to do!

Answer (score 1):

use like below for `click` and `blur`

```
$('#myForm input, #myForm :radio, #myForm :checkbox').on('click blur', function () {
    saveForm();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mani, @Tushar made a similar suggestion in the comments to my original question which is a bit cleaner than this solution.